# How can we have a proof that class in which virtual function is declared is 2 bytes more than one in which is not declared, which is in child class

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{

public:
    virtual void a()
    {

    }
};
class Child:public Base
{
    public:
     void a()
    {

    }
};
int main()
{
    Base b1;
    Child c1;
    cout<<sizeof(b1)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(c1);
    return 0;
}
```

Although the size returns the same for both the objects `b1` and `c1`, that is 4 bytes.  Instead if the keyword virtual is declared than it should 2 bytes more.

Comment: *What* should be two bytes larger? Why *two* bytes? And *why* do you think one object would be larger than the other? Please [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then *edit your question* to elaborate.

Comment: You have observed the behaviour of some compiler in some conditions. Different compiler or different optimization flags probably produce different results. All in all, it is just an implementation detail, it is not standardized and it can change any time. Don't rely on it.

Comment: It most certainly should *not* be two bytes more. It is irrelevant whether or not `Child::a()` is declared `virtual`, as it already is virtual by inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to look more inside the implementation and what compiler produces...

The rule COULD BE the following: When there is any virtual method in the class OR IN ANY INHERITED CLASS, then the object of that class must store so called "pointer to the virtual table of methods" and gets longer (nowaday typically 4 or 8 bytes).

In your example *Base* has virtual method, so it has the pointer to a table and all classes derived from *Base* MUST have also this pointer. That is why you see the same size of objects. Despite there is no "virtual" in *Derived*, *a()* is virtual from inheritance. And it MUST be because if other code works with *Derived* object through a *Base* pointer, it must have the same interface, so *a()* is considered always as virtual.

Note that even using *final* keyword does not remove virtuality. It only provides additional support for optimization but cannot remove virtuality still because the same reason - stable API.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in a 32 bit world (actually mostly 64 bit nowadays) it may get 4 bytes (or 8 bytes) bigger, if anything.

Still, there's no reason for `Child` to be bigger than base.

First of all, if you inherit from a class where `foo` is virtual, even *your* `foo` will be virtual (assuming identical signature), even if you don't explicitly specify it.

But most importantly, the usual implementation of virtual functions is through a pointer to a shared vtable, which means that the only per-object size penalty you pay is a single pointer when you go from a "dumb" class hierarchy to a polymorphic one. It's not a per-function cost, and it affects all the derived classes as well, since the compiler must be able to invoke the correct virtual function blindly given a pointer to a derived object.

(all this optimizations notwhistanding)